# Display bug when using ChromeDriver on MacOSX with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a webpage with selenium in python and since I am on MacOSX when the web driver is launched no text is displayed.

Here is my code :

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,
executable_path=chrome_driver)
driver.get('https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/560')
```

[image: and here is the result]

I use this versions :

```
chrome=67.0.3396.99

chromedriver=2.40.565386 
(45a059dc425e08165f9a10324bd1380cc13ca363),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.5 x86_64)

selenium==3.12.0

python 3.5.5
```

Comment: Your configuration is fine. When you do manually , what happens ?

Comment: I have a normal webpage with the text and everything